# Java: force implementor of an interface to have an immutable name field?

Tags: java

Requirement: I'd like all implementations of an interface to have a well-defined name.

Initially, I thought:

```
interface Fruit {
    public String getName();
}
```

But this allows the user to have a field that is modified at run-time. I want to have an immutable name that is defined before compile/build time.

I've been toying with a couple of other ways to do it, but each has a limitation.

1) Give the name a type, which has slightly more control than free-form strings:

```
interface Fruit {
    public FruitName getName();
}

abstract class FruitName  {
    public final String NAME;
    public FruitName(name) {
        this.NAME = name;
    }
}
```

A user of this class will look like this:

```
class AppleFruitName extends FruitName {
    public AppleFruitName() {
        super("apple");
    }
}

class Apple implements Fruit {
    public FruitName getName() {
        return new AppleFruitName();
    }
}
```

2) Force an implementor of `Fruit` to annotate the name with something:

```
class Apple implements Fruit {
    @FruitName
    public static final NAME = "apple";
    ...    
}
```

Clearly this implementation is far cleaner than (1), but I'm not sure if this is possible in Java? How do you get compile/build to fail if @FruitName is not present?

Comment: How about using the name of the class? For example: `someImplementation.getClass().getCanonicalName()`

Comment: Good suggestion. This is only an example that illustrates my problem, in reality the names and class names will probably be different.

Comment: The first suggestion only ensures that the String in FruitName is final. The implementor that has a FruitName could still provide a completely different FruitName on each call to getName() - this surely goes against what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @plasma147 this is true, but at least there is some measure of control. It is far easier to return an arbitrary string than it is to return an arbitrary implementation of a class. (Valid point, nonetheless)

Comment: Practically the same `new FruitName("apple")` vs `= "apple"` :-D It complicates the Api by adding an extra class that has no function other to give a false sense of security. The sensiblest way is to javadoc it and rely on people to implement the contract that the interface defines. Otherwise,are you going to try to stop them from using aop proxies(or byte code manipulation) to return random values? Are you going to go to the same lengths to check any hash code or equals methods they implement? it may break your app too if they don't fulfill those contracts and you use them in collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do this - without aop, compile time weaving, runtime annotations, scanning at runtime.. etc  is to encapsulate this behaviour in an abstract class:

```
interface Fruit {
  public String getName();
}

abstract class FruitImpl  {
  private final String name;
  public FruitImpl(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public final String getFruitName(){
    return name;
  }
```

}

So at construction time each implementation will be forced to pass in its name and it will not be able to alter it (unless the user is being intentionally malicious). This meets the what the wording of the question suggests.

There is a difference though because some the suggestions seem to assume that all implementations of the interface will have the **same** name - though the question doesn't state that. Is the idea that these implementations will be singletons?

Alternatively, you could use the decorator pattern to wrap the implementation and retrieve the field value once and then always return that value later, like this:

```
class FruitWrapper implements Fruit{
  private final String name;
  public FruitWrapper(Fruit fruit) {
    this.name = fruit.getFruitName();
  }

  public final String getFruitName(){
    return name;
  }
```

}

So you can use it everywhere you would use fruit and it will guarantee to always get the same value.

This way you move the immutability into a class you control.

Comment: The first part of your answer is what I ended up going for. I do not  intend implementations of the interface to have the same name - they should be unique (but that is a different story altogether).

Answer (score 3):

There are several options to enforce this.

- At build time you could write **tests for each** of the `Fruit` classes that look for a field that satisfies your requirements.
- At build time you could write a **single test** that goes through your entire classpath and verifies that each `Fruit` classes satisfies your requirements. A library like [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) could help you to achieve this.
- At compile time you could [**process an Annotation**](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17876.html). I am not sure how you would make sure that each of your classes had an Annotation (as opposed that each class that contains an Annotation is one of the classes in your set.)
- At implementation time, as a slight variation on your request, you could **use an abstract class** instead of an interface and require all implementors to hand you the fixed data in the constructor. That way, you have absolute control over the behaviour.
- At runtime, **while the application launches**, you could check that all implementing classes satify your requirements in the same way an integration test would do it. In a scenario where third parties contribute to your API, this might be the last-stop option if you absolutely have to check it.

I think it is best to use tests for this. You'll have all the certainty you need with far better feedback and much less effort.
If tests are not an option, because you can't control the implementers, I'd go for the abstract class with enforcement during launch as a last resort.

Comment: Sorry, in my head I didn't have a distinction between build-time and compile-time. I'll have to think about the difference.

What if implementors of `Fruit` are part of a separate project? (consumers of your library)

Comment: It is a subtle difference to me.
In this model, build time consists of several phases, of which compile time is just one specific. If you don't differentiate between them, it probably doesn't matter to you and you're well off with tests.

If all are parts of separate projects, you'll either have to set up one test per project, or create one integration test that loads all the modules and performs its verification there.

Comment: Yeah, I understand there is a subtle difference between build and compile. In this context, I'm not sure it matters much - I am open for any solution prior to runtime. The problem is that I will not necessarily be the only consumer of the interface, I cannot force external consumers to write tests.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer with another suggestion to take care of that problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I suspect the abstract class is the easiest way forward.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you confusing `static` and `final`?

```
abstract class FruitName  {
    private final String name;
    public FruitName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is the best you can get in terms of interfaces/classes. You can also use custom annotation, but in slightly different way:

```
@FruitName("apple")
class Apple implements Fruit
```

And also consider using simple class name:

```
Fruit fruit = new Apple();
fruit.getClass().getSimpleName();  //"Apple"
```

But if you depend on class names somewhere, simple refactoring will ruin other parts of the code. So I would consider annotation more stable.

---

Bonus: your problem is easily solvable in [scala](/questions/tagged/scala):

```
trait Fruit {
  val name: String  //abstract AND final
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
  val name = "apple"  //you MUST implement this
}
```

If you don't "implement" `val name` (actually it is an immutable field), compiler will insist on marking `Apple` abstract.

Comment: With regards to your second part, how do you ensure that implementors of `Fruit` have the annotation `@FruitName` at compile time?

Comment: @jabalsad: the only compile-time check I can think of [tag:aspectj] working during compilation. Well, with AspectJ you can do much, much more.

Comment: Well, it doesn't necessarily have to be compile time. I meant to say how do you check the annotation before run-time.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do it with aspectj and compile time waving